# Store country code and address

Tags: bigcommerce

We are integrating our [invoicing app](http://sufio.com) with Bigcommerce and have difficulties obtaining store country code through the Bigcommerce API.

There does not seem to be any field for it in the Store Information resource.

Also, customer addresses are available as separate values (such as street, city or zip code), but we were unable to find anything similar for the store address.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that data isn't available for the store through the API.  The store resource only returns the "display address" as a string...no individual fields are available and no country is required.

You can access the store's default currency  and language codes using the appropriately named fields in the store resource, which would be enough to make an inference as to the country in some cases...but obviously that's a less than ideal solution.